# What is the ABI for the nvidia-open linux kernel driver?

Tags: gpu, nvidia

A year ago NVIDIA open-sourced some linux drivers for their higher-end GPUs (https://github.com/NVIDIA/open-gpu-kernel-modules). I believe these drivers are mostly used through userspace libraries such as CUDA, OpenGL, and some X subsystems. However, can I interact directly with this kernel module? Does it have an ABI? There must be some ABI by which these userspace libraries communicate with it, right? I looked through the source linked above but it is vast and I couldn't make much sense of it. Is the ABI documented anywhere?